# Why can i make protected method public in a successor?

Tags: c++, overriding

I have a protected method `Value`. In successor i overload it in a public method. Why can i do this? I think, it is a violation of encapsulation.

[Example:](http://ideone.com/dtdaij)

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int a) : m_a(a) {};
    virtual ~Foo() {};

    void PrintValue() {
        std::cout << Value() << std::endl;
    }
protected:
    virtual int Value() {
        return m_a;
    }
private:
    int m_a;
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    Bar(int a, int b) : Foo(a), m_b(b) {};
    virtual ~Bar() {};

    int Value() override {
        return m_b;
    }
private:
    int m_b;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Bar b(10, 20);
    b.PrintValue();
    std::cout << b.Value() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
20
20
```

Comment: If it wasn't possible, nothing prevents me from making another public method which calls the protected one. You can't really protect it anyways.

Comment: You don't even need to override. A derived class can expose an inherited protected method via a [using declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration). If you don't want derived classes to see something, make that something private.

Answer (score 3):

Because the visibility/access modifier isn't inherited.